# identify which foreign key is being used ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, I want to get the average quality_score for quality_score_A and Quality_score_B.

this is what I have tried but this gives me the same value in quality_score_a and quality_score_b

```
SELECT AVG (quality_score),AVG (quality_score)
FROM REVIEW
JOIN Score_table on score.quality_score_A
JOIN Score_table on score.quality_score_B
WHERE PRODUCT_ID  = 2
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID;
```

refer to attachment table layout and desired outcome

[image: table layout and outcome]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the condition you want to join on:

```
SELECT   product_id, AVG(a.quality_score), AVG(b.quality_score)
FROM     review r
JOIN     score_table a ON r.quality_score_a = a.score_id
JOIN     score_table b ON r.quality_score_a = b.score_id
WHERE    product_id = 2
GROUP BY product_id
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, I think, is to unpivot the results:

```
select r.product_id,
       avg(case when which = 'a' then s.quality_score end) as a_avg,
       avg(case when which = 'b' then s.quality_score end) as b_avg
from ((select r.product_id, quality_score_a as score_id, 'a' as which
       from reviews r
      ) union all
      (select r.product_id, quality_score_b as score_id, 'b' as which
       from reviews r
      )
     ) r join
     scores s
     on r.score_id = s.score_id
group by r.product_id
```